# Removing dot in front of digits using regular expression in pandas

Tags: regex, pandas

I need to remove the dot in front of digits using regular expressions in pandas.

```
What I have: .9/10 .8/10

What I want: 9/10 8/10
```

I need to use `df.col.str.extract()`.

Also **beware** because there are also float numbers 11.25/10, and in those cases I want to keep the dot.

Comment: try `\.$` this should remove the . at the end of the sentence.

Comment: If you can have floats in there, are you sure they shouldn't become 0.9/10 and 0.8/10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a sample df as you didn't provide one (make sure you provide a sample dataset and your expected outcome in future for others to help)

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'Data' : '20.01/10.'},index=[0])
print(df)
    Data
0   20.01/10.
df['Data'] = df['Data'].str.replace('\.$','')
    print(df)
    Data
0   20.01/10
```

## **Explanation**

In regex, the $ special character ["[matches] the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

assuming you only need to remove the . from the end you could use the pattern above.

If you need to remove from a non digit char then use

```
"\.(?!\d)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this works on the small example you provided (Next time provide more data)

```
import re
re.sub(r' $', '', re.sub(r'|^.', '', re.sub(r', .', ', ', '.9/10, .8/10 ')))
'9/10, 8/10'
```